# Creating a real cron job in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have been trying to create a proper cronjob using the cPanel cronJobs.

To this I have been following the [tutorial](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/).

So far my cronjob seems to be running as I am getting an email saying its running.

My code for the cron is:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://my-domain.co.uk/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

The functions that want running do not to seem to be running though. I'm not sure exactly how it works and really struggling to set a WP Cron.

```
// Cron Jobs -> Email Notifications
add_action( 'schedule-emailNotifications',  'update_db_hourly' );

function my_activation() {
  if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'schedule-emailNotifications' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'hourly', 'schedule-emailNotifications');
  }
}
add_action('wp', 'my_activation');

// Scheduled FUNCTION
function update_db_hourly() 
{
  testEmail();
} // end update_csv_hourly
```

So I believe the cron is running correctly but it does not seem to be running my test script.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Putting this on config file should work

```
define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', 'true');
```